# How to create a class method that references a parent object?

Tags: javascript, class, reference, circular-reference

Currently I have a an object (I'll call it class A) that contains another separate class (class B)  as a value. I'm trying to make everything chainable but if I call a method of class B, there is no way for me to return a reference to class A without adding a separate property to class B referencing class A and making it a circular reference (so far that's not a problem but I want to avoid it if possible). Is it possible to define a class method on class B that references it? If it helps class A is always used to initialize class B.

edit with code:

```js
class A {
    constructor(age,sex){
        this.b=new B
        this.c=0
   }
    exampleMethod (){ 
        this.c +=1 ;
        return this;
   }

class B {
    constructor(){
        this.d=0
   }
    exampleMethodB (){ 
        this.d +=1
        return this;
   }
```

Say I create a new instance of A. If I call exampleMethod() on A, I could keep chaining the exampleMethod() together indefinitely. But the moment I call A.b.exampleMethodB(), I can't return to chaining exampleMethod() because it's referencing an object of the B class now. I can get by this by adding a an object to B that references A, but at the moment I'm wondering if there's a way to keep it in the class methods instead of adding another property to B.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: What does it mean for a class to “[contain] another separate class […] as a value”? It sounds like the circular reference is only manifested in object properties, similar to `const objA = {}, objB = {}; objA.b = objB; objB.a = objA;`. Why do you want to avoid this? How is this related to “chainability”? _“Is it possible to define a class method on class B that references it?”_ — What is “it”? Class A? Please [edit] your post and show the code.

Comment: That is similar to what I'm doing right now but I was trying to figure out if I could avoid adding a property to B just to reference A and instead somehow bind this reference to a class method on B.

Comment: @user8533488 ... do you rely on class syntax explicitly? Would ordinary constructor functions qualify for your code base as well?

Comment: So far it's only class syntax. I do use constructor functions but I can't declare everything at once since at the moment the nested classes of the main class object are only created if the user calls to create them. I did this to be more efficient though tbh I dunno if I should throw it out the window because its not like each nested class is memory heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `A` delegate to `B`. You can create `B` inside of `A` and make the `B` setters chainable. You can define the `parent` of `B` to be `A` (the thing that created it).

```js
class B {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.name = null;
  }
  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }
  getParent() {
    return this.parent;
  }
}

class A {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.b = null; // AKA child
  }
  create() {
    this.b = new B(this);
    return this.b;
  }
  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  getB() {
    return this.b;  // AKA getChild
  }
}

const id = new A(123).create().setName('B').getParent().getId();
console.log(id);
```

Comment: This is my current solution but I was hoping to avoid adding an additional property just for it (largely because I had to rewrite some tests to account for the additional property)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Facade Design pattern. The facade `C` will wrap `B` and `A` and will always returns the instance of `C`. The methods in `C` will be delegated to `A` or `B`.

Facade design pattern link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/facade-design-pattern-introduction/

```
class B {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.name = null;
  }
  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }
  
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.id = null;
  }
  setId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

class C {
  constructor(id) {
    this.A = new A(id);
    this.B = new B();
  }

  setName(name) {
    this.B.setName(name);
    return this;
  }

  setId(id) {
    this.A.setId(id)
  }
}

//You can chain like below
//new C().setName("name").setId(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't think I'll be able to implement it in my current project but this is definitely something I will consider in future ones.

Answer (score 0):

How about inheritance?

```js
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.d = 0;
  }
  exampleMethodB() {
    this.d += 1;
    return this;
  }
}

class A extends B {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.c = 0;
  }
  exampleMethod() {
    this.c += 1;
    return this;
  }
}

const a = new A();

a.exampleMethod()
 .exampleMethodB()
 .exampleMethod()
 .exampleMethodB()
 .exampleMethodB()
 .exampleMethod();

console.log(a);     // { d: 3, c: 3 }
```

Comment: I think normally this would be a great solution. I didn't mention before though that I actually have multiple classes within class A so it would be a nightmare to setup unfortunately.